# IPrincipal in application layer / domain layer

Tags: domain-driven-design

I would like to ask more experienced users if passing IPrincipal interface to domain layer is a good practice or not. My opinion is that it should stay only in application layer. Am I wrong about this? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

The IPrincipal has a meaning for the domain? I think not. This is a .net interface, basically an implemenation detail. However your domain might make use of the concept of a member or user and you could use IPrincipal as the implementation, although I don't think the domain would need exactly the behaviour of IPrincipal.

So my answer is don't pass it unless the domain really needs it at such.

Comment: I agree. It is a .NET implementation interface, not concerned with domain logic. Even if your domain has the concept of a user/member, entities should not implement this interface. The application layer should use this interface for authentication/authorisation of the caller